# I can't create react app using npx create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, npm, deployment, create-react-app, npx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkVjE.png)

I have tried to resolve the issue by deleting the node and re-installing it and whatever I do it is ending up like this. I have also deleted the node modules and re-installed the react but it does change anything

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\heman\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1072:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.3.1
I don't even know what is this error

Answer (score 0):

I will advise you to use the LTS version of Node.js. Reinstall Node.js with [v18](https://nodejs.org/dist/v18.16.1/node-v18.16.1-x64.msi), you should also change your directory from OneDrive directory, it might be as a result of path permission.

Let me know if the problem persist.

Comment: i have already using v20.3.1 and previously i was able to install but now it is not able to create app